# Sudoers settings for ansible user

Tags: sudo, ansible, ansible-tower

I have made a playbook which does something like this:

shell: source ~/.bashrc && some_command |awk something more

become: yes

become user: a_user

become_method: sudo

My Ansible_user that connects to the target host should not be able to sudo -i on target host, nor should it have 'Ansible_user (ALL)=ALL NOPASSWD: ALL' entry in the /etc/sudoers.

I want it to be able to execute some commands as a_user (including bash builtins like source). I found in the documentation that Ansible will try to execute something like this:

1. log on as Ansible_user
2. Execute $Ansible_user sudo -u commands_from_playbook

Yet, when I try to run the playbook all I get is:
module_stderr: Shared connection to host_ip_here closed
msg: MODULE FAILURE See stderr for the exact error

No stderr is presented despite the job running as 'verbosity 3'

When user is granted sudo -i and/or ALL in sudoers, the script runs as expected...

What should be the /etc/sudoers entry? Probably I should use something like
Ansible_user ALL = (a_user) NOPASSWD: and_something_here (/bin/bash for builtins?)

Any hints?

Comment: [privilege escalation must be general](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_privilege_escalation.html#privilege-escalation-must-be-general). This is a known limitation. If this is not acceptable in your environment, don't use ansible privilege escalation.

Comment: Thank you Zeitounautor. I think your answer settles the case.